# Adding a UIElement child to a Panel implicitly adds it to the UIElementCollection for the Panel element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am reading an MSDN article for learning XAML: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/fundamentals/xaml?view=netdesktop-5.0#content-properties-and-collection-syntax-combined

It says the collection's element tag can be omitted, based on the XAML rules for processing collections such as IList.
[image]

I can't find the XAML rules for processing collection that it says.
I have searched for an hour to find out this rule. I can only find out information

> "The Children collection of a Panel element can only consist of
> UIElement objects. Adding a UIElement child to a Panel implicitly adds
> it to the UIElementCollection for the Panel element."

in this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.panel.children?view=net-5.0

Please let me know what is XAML rules for processing collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things going on here, all described by [the documentation page you referenced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/fundamentals/xaml?view=netdesktop-5.0#content-properties-and-collection-syntax-combined), but in some cases elaborated elsewhere:

1. The `StackPanel.Children` element may be omitted. This is because the `Panel` class, which `StackPanel` inherits, uses the [`[ContentProperty]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute) attribute to indicate that the `Children` property is to be used when content is specified without an element tag.
2. An element tag for the collection type itself may be omitted, because the `Panel.Children` property has the type `UIElementCollection`, which implements `IList`, and the XAML syntax rules specify that the XAML compiler will implicitly add items declared as content elements to the existing collection for the current element. This is documented by the [Collections and collection types for XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/xaml-services/collections-and-types) page. Note that in this case, the collection itself is implicitly specified, per the previous point.
3. In fact, one **may not** actually specify the `UIElementCollection` element tag, because this would indicate the instantiation of a whole new collection object to be assigned to the `Children` property, but [the property itself is read-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.panel.children?view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Controls_Panel_Children), so this is prohibited. I find the documentation's explanation (which it provides parenthetically in the passage you show in your post) misleading; it is correct to note that the class has no parameterless constructor, but there are ways in XAML around that limitation. The real problem is that even if one could construct a new instance of the collection, it can't be assigned to the `Children` property.